# Ajustar local do card

Tags: html, css, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Bom dia, estou criando uma pagina web responsiva e gostaria que o topo do card sempre ficasse exatamente no meio da imagem que coloquei de background, independente do tamanho da tela. Não faço ideia de como fazer isso. Me ajudem por favor.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body {
 overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fundo1{
 display: table;
   width: 100%;
   height: 35%;
   padding: 100px 0;
   color: white;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526374965328-7f61d4dc18c5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80') no-repeat bottom center scroll;
   background-position: 30% 45%;
   background-size: cover;
   filter: blur(6px);
   position: absolute;
}

.meucard{
 margin-top: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Pagina web</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="fundo1">
  
 </div>
 <div class="container meucard">
  <div class="card text-center">
   <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Principal</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Contato</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Teste</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar position ou display flex, mas o ideal creio eu seria colocar o card dentro da div fundo1, mas se não quiser pode aplicar no body ou colocar um wrapper nos dois o importante é no seu caso pode ficar assim: 
position

```
body {
    position: relative;
} 

.meucard {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

usando flexbox

```
.body {
    display: ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você pode utilizar **flexbox**, mas antes é necessário fazer algumas alterações no seu código.

```
       * {
            margin: 0;
            padding:0;
        }

        html, body {
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .fundo1{
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            padding: 100px 0;
            background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526374965328-7f61d4dc18c5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80') no-repeat bottom center scroll;
            background-position: 30% 45%;
            background-size: cover;
            position: relative;
        }


        .fundo1::after {
            content: '';
            filter: blur(6px);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            z-index: 100;
        }

        .meucard {
            min-height:100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items:center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .card {
            z-index: 1000000;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

Utilizei o pseudo-elemento *::after* para gerar o efeito de blur sem sobrescrever outros elementos de dentro da  e dei um *z-index* para deixar ele por trás dos outros elementos.

```
    <div class="fundo1">

        <div class="container meucard">
            <div class="card col-12 text-center">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Principal</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Contato</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Teste</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

No HTML, juntei tudo em uma única , que seria o correto.
Como você está usando Bootstrap, uma coisa interessante é procurar usar corretamente o sistema de grids dele, que isso até facilitaria para você realizar esse tipo de alteração, afinal o framework está ai para te ajudar :).

Um exemplo de como usar o Bootstrap corretamente:

```
<div class='container'>
     <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-3'>
               <h1>Conteúdo da minha primeira coluna.</h1>
          </div>

          <div class='col-3'>
               <h1>Conteúdo da minha segunda coluna.</h1>
          </div>

          <div class='col-6'>
               <h1>Conteúdo da minha terceira coluna.</h1>     
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Dá uma lida na documentação do Bootstrap (tem em português também), que vai te ajudar bastante.

Espero ter ajudado, abração!